# Regular expression - match string up to a another string optionally

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a message in PHP that may (or may not) fall between start end end markers, like so:

```
Some rubbish
------- start message -------
Here's the actual message
------- end message ---------
more rubbish
```

And I'm trying this expression:

```
/^(?:(?:.*)?\n-{3,} ?begin message ?-{3,})?(.*)(?:\n-{3,} ?end message ?-{3,})?/is
```

However it seems the (.*) also captures all the text from "Here" to the end of the string. If I make the match for the end marker non-conditional it captures OK, but then wouldn't match if the end marker isn't there.

It does work if I give the (.*) a more restrictive character class like ([a-zA-Z -\s]*), but I don't want to be so restrictive.

Do I need a lookahead or something?

Comment: Use `start` rather than `begin` in the pattern. What output are you seeking?

Comment: Do you not want the `(.*)` to be not greedy? I.e. change to `(.*?)`?

Comment: @JonStirling: No-no, do not use lazy dot matching when parsing. Use *unroll-the-loop* approach. Like [`-{7} start message -{7}([^-]*(?:-(?!-{6} end message -{7})[^-]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/eR5oS0/2).

Comment: @stribizhev Will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Try this: `/.*?\-{3,}\s*start\s*message\s*\-{3,}\s*(.*?)\s*\-{3,}\s*end\s*message\s*\-{3,}.*/is`

Comment: @MayurKoshti: [It does not even match](https://regex101.com/r/zB3tK7/1).

Comment: Oops! I used "is" instead of "gs". Note that I am using Kiki and it works correctly.

Comment: @stribizhev your approach worked. I *kind of* understand it. The start marker also needs to be optional so I put back in the optional section from  the start of my original regexp and it seems to work. If you add an answer rather than a comment I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to match anything beginning with `-{7} start message -{7}` and up to `------- end message -------`:

```
-{7} start message -{7}([^-]*(?:-(?!-{6} end message -{7})[^-]*)*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR5oS0/2)

The regex is based on a [*unrolling-the-loop* method](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

The regex breakdown:

- `-{7} start message -{7}` - matches exactly 7 hyphens, a space, `start message`, space and agains 7 hyphens.
- `([^-]*(?:-(?!-{6} end message -{7})[^-]*)*)` - Capture group 1 matching...

  - `[^-]*` - 0 or more characters other than `-`
  - `(?:-(?!-{6} end message -{7})[^-]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

    - `-(?!-{6} end message -{7})` - a hyphen that is not followed by 6 hyphens, space, `end message`, space and 7 hyphens
    - `[^-]*` - 0 or more characters other than hyphen.

> The start marker also needs to be optional

Well, you really can omit `-{7} start message -{7}`, or put it into an optional group:

```
(?:-{7} start message -{7})?([^-]*(?:-(?!-{6} end message -{7})[^-]*)*)
^^^ ------ optional -------^
```

Note that if you just omit it, the pattern will be matching empty strings, too.

Comment: I will add explanations when my kids go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
start\s+?message\s+?-------\r?\n([\d\D]+?)-------\s+?end\s+?message
```

If you want to know why I use `[\d\D]` instead of `.`:

In many environments the `.` does NOT include the `\n` character and the regex will stop once it finds one, you can bypass this using the `m` modificator but it doesn't always work. The `[\d\D]` includes the `\n`, you can use any group of characters that are oposites for this, it's all the same: `[\s\S]`, `[\w\W]` ...

Comment: This is the same inefficient regex based on lazy dot matching. Not recommended. You can also see from the OP regex that the end part is *optional*, and you make it obligatory.